# FullCalendar-2.7.3 events not showing on initial load

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In my console, I get this error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'clone' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of null
```

which is in this loop in the _fetchEventSource(source, callback) method:

```
for (i = 0; i < fetchers.length; i++) {
    res = fetchers[i].call(
        t, // this, the Calendar object
        source,
        rangeStart.clone(), // rangeStart is undefined
        rangeEnd.clone(),
        options.timezone,
        callback
    );
```

The problem is that rangeStart is not set. However, if I use the buttons in the default header to change from "month" view to "week" view, and back again, the events load.

I can't figure out why rangeStart isn't being set initially but gets set just fine if I switch the view.

For the sake of completeness, here's my JS to call the calendar:

```
$('.event-calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    eventLimit: true,
    events: {
        url: '/events/json',
        color: '#0060db',
        textColor: 'white'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is compatible problem with newest JQuery 3. I can't help but if you want to get working FullCallendar you should temporary reverse your JQuery to 2.x or 1.x line and wait for FullCalendar update.

Comment: Yeah, found that out the next day.

Comment: jQuery 3 support was added in FullCalendar v2.8.0. This should no longer be an issue.