# When loaded as partial, FullCalendar renders but no triggers are activated. No data is loaded

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

**Update 2017/03/29 18:00**

After many attempts, I found out that if the page loads with the 'Calendar' TAB being the active TAB it loads correctly, however, when the page is NOT the active tab I get the rangeStart error and no data gets loaded...

Though not clear why, I can at least make it work...somewhat...

---

**Update 2017/03/29 16:00**

We've made progress, fortunately through StackOverflow obviously...
first I found attached two posts:
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Which brought me to the fact that the data needs to be called async.

Another post:

[Maping Events to FullCalender using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790520/maping-events-to-fullcalender-using-json/38831073#38831073)

Then gave me the hint how to render the JSON that comes back (my c# controller returns JSON data)

So, I altered my code as per below:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            //defaultDate: moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
            timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetDiaryEvents", "Calendar")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                        start: start.format(),
                        end: end.format()
                    },
                    success: function(events)
                    {
                        //debugger;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);         
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
                    }
```

Which works nicely, however...it **ONLY** does so if the `Calendar` page is set to be the active page. If it is not the active page, the data does not get loaded and no data gets loaded even when switching views from month -> week -> day and back...

It still gives the `rangeStart` error after loading the full `Index.cshtml` page and no data gets loaded and no calendar is rendered.

Adding a 'render call' in the JQuery Tab call solves the 'no rendering' on the page. But still doesn't solve the no-data problem:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/

I found this post:
[FullCalendar-2.7.3 events not showing on initial load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821389/fullcalendar-2-7-3-events-not-showing-on-initial-load)

That would indicate that my standard VS2015 jquery-3.1.1.js would be the main culpritt, anybody able to confirm that ?

---

**The problem:**

When loaded as partial, FullCalendar renders but no triggers are activated.
No data is loaded.

**Using**

- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- MVC 5.2.3.0
- FullCalender 3.0.0
- jquery-3.1.1
- jquery-ui-1.12.1
- VS2015 in C#

**The Setup**

The page with the `<div id="#calendar"></div>` is a cshtml meant to load as a partial under a tabbed lay-out.

in the `_Layout.cshtml` of the tabbed `Index.cshtml` all major js/css gets loaded as per below:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Main";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Some Application</title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/datatables")
```

When clicking 'Calendar Tab' the `_prtCalendar.cshtml` will be shown.

```
        <!-- Calendar -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="_calendar">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Company/_prtCalendar.cshtml", Model)
        </div>
```

`_prtCalendar.cshtml` has a  `$(document).ready(function () {` section that loads the Calendar. The Index.cshtml (in which the document is a part has a `$(document).ready(function () {` as well...

The JQuery-FullCalendar within that section all refer to `CalendarController` through `@Url.Action('<action>,"Calendar")`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            //defaultDate: moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
            timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            events: '@Url.Action("GetDiaryEvents", "Calendar")',
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                alert('You clicked on event id: ' + calEvent.id
                    + "\nSpecial ID: " + calEvent.someKey
                    + "\nAnd the title is: " + calEvent.title);

            },
```

**The Trick**

If I load `_prtCalendar.cshtml` directly, 
i.e. I load all js/css directly in/through the `_prtCalendar.cshtml` page and display without `_Layout.cshtml` and `Index.cshtml` all works fine and all functions within `CalendarController` are called correctly.

However, **IF** I load `_prtCalendar.cshtml` as partial, things seem to go awry and nothing gets loaded and I get a JS error:

> TypeError: rangeStart is undefined[Learn More] 
>   fullcalendar.js:11023:6

Now, I would assume that is somehow because the `rangeStart` apparently doesn't get set properly however I do not seem to be able to identify **WHY** not.

`_prtCalendar.cshtml` Loads both `fullcalendar.js` and `moment.min.js` first before attempting the `$(document).ready` call through below lines.

```
<link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

If I use the F12 Debugger, I can see that the `$('#calendar')` function is called but it fails on the `rangeStart` call.
Other buttons on other TAB's (in same `Index.cshmtl`) that refer to different controllers get called correctly when called from `Index.cshmtl`.

Any help would be very very welcome...:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is too bloody simple...really...

Down at the bottom of the `$(document).ready` is a line that says:

```
CalLoading = false;
```

Change that to:

```
CalLoading = true;
```

And it would appear that that solves the problem...